# Catch result of a function

Tags: javascript

I´m uploading files with firebase firestore.
I want to return a promise (catch) if there are no files uploaded (files.length === 0)

```
const uploadFile = (files) => {

    if (files.length > 0) {
        const file = files[0];

        return storage
            .ref()
            .child("files/" + file.name)
            .put(file);

    } else {
        // what should i do here so i can catch it?
    }
};
```

then in my code I call it like this.

```
uploadFile(files)
    .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("file uploaded", snapshot);
    })
    .catch(() => console.log("no files uploaded"))
```

thank you.

Comment: throw an error from else ( return a rejected promise )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply throw an `Error` to invoke the `catch`:

```js
const uploadFile = async files => {
  if (files.length === 0) throw new Error(`No files provided`);
  return storage.ref().child(`files/${files[0].name}`).put(files[0]);
};

uploadFile([]).catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`));
```

If you go with this method, it's important that you make your `uploadFile` function `async`, so it returns a promise.

Comment: spent an hour seeing an error until I saw that the function needs async. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a `rejected promise`

```js
const uploadFile = (files) => {

  if (files.length > 0) {
    const file = files[0];

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('Yes'), 10)
    })
  } else {
    return new Promise(function(resoleve, reject) {
      reject("No files found")
    })
  }
};


uploadFile([])
  .then((snapshot) => {
    console.log("file uploaded", snapshot);
  })
  .catch(() => console.log("no files uploaded"))
```

Comment: like this. because is not an error. is just no file uploaded. thank you so much!

Comment: Conceptually, a rejected promise is very similar to an error

Comment: @Gershom that's just for an example, and if that gives me downvote i am happy

Comment: @Gershom blindly copy pasting shouldn't be a practice at all 